# SELECT all items in common between two users from a SINGLE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table

xyz (to store the relations between user and item)

```
| user_id |  item_id |
----------------------
```

An item can belong to one or more user and viceversa.

So, given the **user_id = A** and **user_id = B** how can I do a mysql query to select all the ***items the belong both to user A and user B***?

Comment: some sample data would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT Item_ID
FROM xyz
WHERE  User_ID IN ('A','B')
GROUP BY Item_ID
HAVING COUNT(distinct user_id) = 2
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ad5/4)

Comment: @Andomar: I think it should be: `count(distinct user_id) = 2`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.item_id
FROM xyz AS a
  JOIN xyz AS b
    ON b.item_id = a.item_id
WHERE a.user_id = 'A'
  AND b.user_id = 'B' ;
```

if the combination of `(user_id, item_id)` is not unique, make that `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```
select item_id from xyx
where item_id IN(select item_id from xyz where user_id ='A')
and item_id IN(select item_id from xyz where user_id ='B')
```

Answer (score 1):

This would suffice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ad5/6

```
select item_id
from xyz
group by item_id
having sum(user_id in ('A','B')) = 2
```

ANSI SQL'y way:

```
select item_id
from xyz
group by item_id
having sum(case when user_id in ('A','B') then 1 end) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**One way can be**

SELECT temp1.item_id FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM pcadminlogging
 WHERE userid='A'
) 
AS temp1
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM pcadminlogging 
WHERE userid='B'
)
 AS temp2
ON temp1.item_id=temp2.item_id
WHERE 
temp1.userid in ('A','B')